# Why are scenes featuring Robert Downey Jr. depicted in black and white, while Cillian Murphy's scenes are shown in vibrant colors?

Tags: plot-explanation, oppenheimer

In the movie "Oppenheimer," initially the Robert Downey Jr. appears in scenes that are presented in the traditional black and white format, while Cillian Murphy appears in scenes that are vibrantly colored. This striking visual contrast adds depth to the actors' portrayals of their roles.  What was Nolan's perspective on these events, and what message was he trying to get across?

Answer (score 15):

According to an [interview](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a44078733/oppenheimer-black-and-white-sequences-christopher-nolan/) with Christopher Nolan, the director of “Oppenheimer,” the choice to film certain segments in black-and-white was due to the various plot strands in the film. Nolan said,

> “I knew that I had two timelines that we were running in the film. **One
> is in color, and that’s Oppenheimer’s subjective experience.** That’s
> the bulk of the film. **Then the other is a black and white timeline.
> It’s a more objective view of his story from a different character’s
> point of view”.**

So, it seems that the black-and-white scenes featuring Robert Downey Jr. represent a more objective view of Oppenheimer’s story from a different character’s point of view, while Cillian Murphy’s scenes in vibrant colors represent Oppenheimer’s subjective experience.

Comment: Note that B&W parts are often used to show "*historical/news*" footage, giving them some kind of legitimacy, such as "*this is what really happened, we shot it live*".

Comment: "The biopic, Nolan’s follow-up to *Tenet*, will follow J Robert Oppenheimer (Cillian Murphy) as he partakes in the Manhattan Project, with the" ... "partakes in the Manhattan Project" is a hilarious way to write that.

Comment: "Why my good sir, I do occasionally partake in a little nuclear science and weapons of mass destruction myself!"

Comment: One example of what @OldPadawan mentions is "Thirteen Days", a film about the Cuban Missile Crisis. It has several scenes based on well-known press photos of Kennedy and other players during that crisis. Those scenes start in B&W, with the actors posed to match the photo reference, and then transition to colour as the action starts.

Comment: Forrest Gump uses that technique too for blending either the character or the fictional story with History: meeting with JFK - Wallace's speech at UA - KKK footage

Comment: @OldPadawan Ah yes, so it does.

Comment: *Memento*, one of Nolan's first movies has also 2 timelines, one running forward in B&W and the other running backward in color.